# declaring switch statement and then calling it later

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

I've developed a code that creates concentric rectangles of alphabets based on the input, unfortunately as there's no dictionary function in C, I've used switch statement to convert my numerical value to alphabets. I'm getting the desired output but since I've two different methods for odd and even inputs, I've to declare switch statement in both the sections of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, n;

int main() {
printf("Enter the Number: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

if(a%2 == 0)
{
    n = a/2;
    printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - j;
            }
            int value = z+1;

          // printf("%d ", value);
        switch(value){
          case 1:
             printf("A ");
             break;
          case 2:
            printf("B " );
            break;
          case 3:
             printf("C " );
             break;
          case 4:
             printf("D " );
             break;
          case 5:
             printf("E " );
             break;
          case 6:
             printf("F ");
             break;
          case 7:
            printf("G " );
            break;
          case 8:
             printf("H " );
             break;
          case 9:
             printf("I " );
             break;
          case 10:
             printf("J " );
             break;
          case 11:
            printf("K " );
            break;
          case 12:
             printf("L " );
             break;
          case 13:
             printf("M " );
             break;
          case 14:
             printf("N " );
             break;
          case 15:
             printf("O ");
             break;
          case 16:
            printf("P " );
            break;
          case 17:
             printf("Q " );
             break;
          case 18:
             printf("R " );
             break;
          case 19:
             printf("S " );
             break;
          case 20:
             printf("T ");
             break;
          case 21:
            printf("U " );
            break;
          case 22:
             printf("V " );
             break;
          case 23:
             printf("W " );
             break;
          case 24:
             printf("X " );
             break;
          case 25:
             printf("Y " );
             break;
          case 26:
             printf("Z " );
             break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else
{
  n = (a/2)+1;
  printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - j;
            }
            int value = z+1;

          // printf("%d ", value);
                    switch(value){
          case 1:
             printf("A");
             break;
          case 2:
            printf("B");
            break;
          case 3:
             printf("C");
             break;
          case 4:
             printf("D");
             break;
          case 5:
             printf("E");
             break;
          case 6:
             printf("F");
             break;
          case 7:
            printf("G");
            break;
          case 8:
             printf("H");
             break;
          case 9:
             printf("I");
             break;
          case 10:
             printf("J");
             break;
          case 11:
            printf("K");
            break;
          case 12:
             printf("L");
             break;
          case 13:
             printf("M");
             break;
          case 14:
             printf("N");
             break;
          case 15:
             printf("O");
             break;
          case 16:
            printf("P");
            break;
          case 17:
             printf("Q");
             break;
          case 18:
             printf("R");
             break;
          case 19:
             printf("S");
             break;
          case 20:
             printf("T");
             break;
          case 21:
            printf("U");
            break;
          case 22:
             printf("V");
             break;
          case 23:
             printf("W");
             break;
          case 24:
             printf("X");
             break;
          case 25:
             printf("Y");
             break;
          case 26:
             printf("Z");
             break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the Number: 7
The Output is: 
A A A A A A A 
A B B B B B A 
A B C C C B A 
A B C D C B A 
A B C C C B A 
A B B B B B A 
A A A A A A A
```

Since that multiple declaration of switch, the code gets unwantedly lengthy so I was wondering if there was a way to declare the switch functionality once and then call it into the main function anytime needed, but I've ultimately failed so far, I've tried creating a function for switch statement with pointers but it seemingly didn't work. Is it possible to declare switch and cases once and call it as many times required in question?

Please ignore the aesthetics of the code.

Edit: Based on the support and suggestions in the comment, I've developed a simpler version of the code, I'm uploading it here in case if this could be of any help to the community or new contributors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, n;
char letters[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y', 'Z' };
int main() {
printf("Enter the Number: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

if(a%2 == 0)
{
    n = a/2;
    printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - j;
            }
              printf("%c ", letters[z]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else
{
  n = (a/2)+1;
  printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - j;
            }
        printf("%c ", letters[z]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

But rather than an optimal way, my question was if we could somehow call switch statement in the program (generally, not particularly here)

Comment: You can map your characters and their ascii value. Like `printf("%c ", (char)(value - 1 + 'A'));`

Comment: To get rid of the `switch` in a more portable way that doesn't rely on ASCII (sorry @Joel) use a simple array: `char letters[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', ..., 'Z' };` Then use `value - 1` as index into that array to get the character to print (after validation of `value` of course).

Comment: Your code also has for loop repeated, only the limit is changing in the loop condition.

Comment: @Joel: The C standard does not require implementations to use ASCII or to use a character set in which the letters are consecutive, and students should not be instructed to do that without cautioning them about that issue. Also, the cast to `char` is useless; as an argument corresponding to `...` in the `printf` declaration, it will be promoted to `int`.

Comment: More generally, if you ever have common code it's a great use-case for *functions*.

Comment: @kiner_shah No actually both the loops have different if conditions, like 1st has (z > 2 * n - 1 - i) while second (z > 2 * n - 2 - i), I've tried various ways like declaring "1" and "2" as variables and call in the if statement but lately that rather complicates the code,.

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava, you should be able to generalize that.

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava, check out my answer :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can generalize your loops and eliminate switch statements by using a lookup table:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern(int a)
{
    static const char* alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int n = (a % 2 == 0 ? a / 2 : a / 2 + 1);

    // The above line is equivalent to
    // int n;
    // if (a % 2 == 0)
    //   n = a / 2
    // else
    //   n = a / 2 + 1

    int loop_len = (a % 2 == 0 ? 2 * n : 2 * n - 1);
    printf("\nThe output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < loop_len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < loop_len; j++)
        {
            int z = i;
            if (z > loop_len - 1 - i)
            {
                z = loop_len - 1 - i;
            }
            if (z > j)
            {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > loop_len - 1 - j)
            {
                z = loop_len - 1 - j;
            }
            int value = z + 1;
            printf("%c ", alpha[value - 1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int a, n;
    printf("Enter the Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    print_pattern(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer is admirable but I'm still not familiar with operations like "?" and thus I tried to keep it in layman language, though thank you for you optimal response but it doesn't assist my question of "If switch statement can be declared and called later in the program?"

Comment: `condition ? true_case : false_case` is ternary operator, read about it. Also, switch statements aren't variables which can be declared for later use. You can use a function like this though. :-)

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava, I put some explanation in code, check it out

Comment: Helps a lot, really grateful <3

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava, do upvote and select my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: @kinner_shah I actually don't have enough rep to upvote : ), we can only after 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

You can portably convert an index into the alphabet to a letter using `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"[value-1]`. The string literal creates an array, and `[value-1]` gets an element from the array.

You can non-portably convert using `'A' + (value-1)`. This works in C implementations in which the letters are consecutive in alphabetical order in the execution character set, which is very common but not required by the C standard.

You can use the same code in multiple places by putting either your switch statement or the code above into a function call:

```
int IndexToLetter(int value)
{
    static const char Alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    return Alphabet[value-1];
}
```

Then the function can be called with `IndexToLetter(value)`. For example, to print the letter and a space, you could use `printf("%c ", IndexToletter(value));` or:

```
putchar(IndexToLetter(value));
putchar(' ');
```

Since you did not show your “function for switch statement with pointers but it seemingly didn't work,” no diagnosis of the errors in it can be made.

### Notes

The string literal `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"` uses 27 bytes because it includes a terminating null byte. This waste is unlikely to matter in a program. However, the `Alphabet` array shown above avoids this by limiting the array size to 26 bytes. We can get the same effect with a compound literal: `return (char [26]){"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}[value-1]`.

To simplify the code looking up the letter from `value-1` to `value`, you could change `int value = z+1;` to `int value = z;`, another simplification.

Comment: Is there a reason why the return type of `IndexToLetter()` is `int` instead of `char`?

Comment: @nielsen: C handles characters using `int`. The type of a character literal is an `int`. A `char` value returned by a function will be promoted to `int` in most uses. There is little or not value in making the return type `char`. In some situations, it can make the compiler insert needless instructions to narrow and widen the value.